# Transition from ABCpdf07 to ABCpdf8 - images are not displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, abcpdf

I am trying to make the transition from ABCpdf07 to ABCpdf8. We use this in methods for printing various shipping labels in PDF format. This generally works, with the exeption of files with images in them. Here is the code used for putting in the html to the Document:

```
    public void AddHtml(string html, string frame, string nextPageFrame)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPageFrame))
            nextPageFrame = frame;
        Document.Units = UnitType.Mm;
        Document.Rect.String = frame;

        int i = Document.AddImageHtml(html);

        while (true)
        {
            if (!Document.Chainable(i))
                break;
            Document.Page = Document.AddPage();
            Document.Rect.String = nextPageFrame;
            i = Document.AddImageToChain(i);
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= Document.PageCount; j++)
        {
            Document.PageNumber = j;
            Document.Flatten();
        }
    }
```

frame and nextFrame are simply values determining how large the pages are. The html works in debugging when I view it in HTML view. But after this method, when the Document gets saved, the images are not shown on the page - in stead there's the broken-image-icon. The images are saved locally in the project folder (c:\etc...). Have tripple-checked that the links are working.

Really cant wrap my head around why the images aren't displayed properly. Any help?

Edit: 
My xslt document finds the image like this

```
    <xsl:template match="//TheWrapper">
    ...
    <img class="someClass">
       <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select ='LogoLocation' />
       </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
    ...
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems version 8 of ABCpdf has another method of passing the images. This is because they wanted to not be dependant on IE (which it loads in the background some time during the processing). I'm not very knowledgable with the details here.

Anyway - Happened to open the logo filepath in Chrome, and it added 'file:///' automatically, so I tried doing that in my code, and it worked! Simply prefix the logo filepaths with 'file:///' and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The probleme is that the http header response is bad format for abcpdf, use the good header http response for your image. Take example with a good example and look http header in firefox debugguer and reproduce this http header repsonse for your image.

Or look if the close methode of http stream response for your image is good if you send manual image by code server.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to describe here.  Perhaps you could add some code examples?

Comment: With .Net ASP MVC there are a FileStreamResult, the good example : image.Save( stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg ); stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin ); return new FileStreamResult( stream, "image/jpeg" );

Comment: Sorry i have loose my experience code for this problem, but I have already this problem, and the browser printed image, but no Abcpdf, the reason it is that the http response has bad

Comment: I am using Document.Save(theSavePath) for saving the document, not the stream functionality

Comment: I talk about Image sending, no PDF document saving, the error is in image HTML page, no PDF document, because Abcpdf engine not reconize the image in html page. (I suppose).

Comment: the generated image html looks fine to me:
<image class="someClass" src="C:\someUrl.jpg"></image>

Comment: note: I changed the tags from img to image, as the img ones did not seem to make the closing tags